# sonarqube not excluding test folder

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 5.6.1 with gradle plugin 2.1.

I can't exclude test folders from report issues. 
property 'sonar.exclusions', 'src/test/**, build/**' 
Test folder is not excluded while build folder is.

I can exclude the whole test folder, however, all my test source and results are gone. Unit test result is important. I need them.
property 'sonar.test.exclusions', 'src/test/**'

How can I archive both exclude test source from reporting issue and showing unit test result?

This is a bug. Sonarqube must provide a way to stop reporting issue in test code. My directive is to fail the build if the quality gate fails. It is not correct to fail my build because test code has quality issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please edit your question to add code snippets of your current configuration.

Comment: try `sonar.exclusions=test/, build/` instead of `sonar.exclusions=src/test/, build/`. Path in `sonar.exclusions` property should be relative path to `sonar.sources`. if `sonar.sources` is set to `src` and you want to exclude `src\test` folder then `sonar.exclusions` property should be set to `test` not `src\test`

Comment: See [help](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles) here.

Comment: Thanks Vikas. I have tried test/**, **/test/**, src/test/**, **/src/test/**. None of them stop sonarqube from reporting issue from my test code. I have to exclude the test in sonar.test.exclusion to stop sonarqube from reporting issue. But I will have no unit test in sonarqube.

Comment: **Check this out** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111757/sonarqube-not-excluding-test-files/42118149?noredirect=1#comment71475954_42118149