# sonarQube Not excluding test files

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have added

```
sonar.exclusion=src/test/java/**/*.*
sonar.test.exclusions=**/test/**/*.*
```

properties into the sonar-project.properties file. But it is not excluding the test files when creating sonarQube code coverage document. I am using jenkins as building tool

Comment: (   sonar.exclusion=src/test/java/**/*.*
sonar.test.exclusions=**/test/**/*.*          )
These are the properties

Comment: why wouldn't you want to check test files with sonar?

Comment: Code Duplication is present in TestCases.So No point in fixing the code when are about to go for production

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to exclude tests *from*. Finding issues?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions) it should be `sonar.exclusions`, not `sonar.exclusion`.

Comment: It got resolved.  We need to keep it like **/test/**/*.java       . I was confused with (*)->zero or more characters (**)-> zero or more directories

Comment: You mean `src/test/java` did not exist and `sonar.exclusion` works even if the final `s` is missing?

Comment: yes I changed that to sonar.exclusions.   In documentation they have clearly mentioned to use sonar.test.exclusions for test directories

Comment: that should have been "no", not "yes"